# Android Studio is very slow

Tags: performance, gradle, android-studio

I have a project with about 20 modules inside. Gradle clean takes about 5min. As ell if i add a new module gradle update projects needs more than 5min.

There are no dependencies to external libraries. Dependencies are only inside the project between several modules.

I had same Project without gradle and it worked fine. I did not convert the old project to gradle. I have created a new project with the file structure recomended by gradle. But with this performance this is not very usefull...

Any idea what's going wrong with gradle?

Comment: Apparently, it is still under heavy development. Meanwhile all we can do is just wait for some updates. Please take a look at this: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RicardoAmaral/posts/e9PG6vSN5w3

Answer (score 8):

Just create a file named gradle.properties in the following directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:Users<username>.gradle (Windows)
```

Add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Source: https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/

Answer (score 3):

My Android studio in Ubuntu was too slow and I have done these things to speed up to very fast.
in the welcome screen click (you can also go to it by file>close project)

```
 >configure>project default>
>code style > compiler > 
  click the following options 
     -make project automatically
     -use in process build
     -configure on demand
then in compiler (below the first one)
     - give build process heap size as 1000 or 1500
       (it will take a lot of RAM but Android studio will be extremely fast)
       give the same heap size for Android build and gradle build in the below tabs
```

Hope it will help

Comment: i have the same isues. eclipse is on fire where as studio is truggling to start.. experimental application should never be released to masses.

Comment: I agree. Many people have recipes about how to make it fast, but it's still slow. Something which you don't need in Eclipse. I just tested an old app in it. I swear I was feeling like crying how fast it build the app and showed up.

Answer (score 2):

This could help too:

> If you notice that Android Studio works slowly, consider the possibility to reduce the number of folders under antivirus protection.
>
> Each antivirus check in your project consumes resources. You can significantly improve the performance, if you exclude certain folders from the antivirus protection.

Source: tip of the day from Android Studio.

Edit: The same point was made in the 2019 Google I/O talk: https://youtu.be/8rfvfojtRss?list=WL&t=756

Comment: Does Android Studio have antivirus protection? Or is it talking about a third party product that you could have running on your computer by default?

Comment: ^ Yeah. I'm sorta confused as to what this means.

Comment: @DavidArgyleThacker Its talking about third party software. Usually your antivirus with default options won't bother you

Answer (score 1):

Set Custom VM options in
Help-->EDIT Custom VM options.

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

File-->Setting-->Build Executions

Compiler-->Command-line options set **--offline**.

Gradle-->**check OfflineWork.**

Launch SDK Manager--> **Download HAXM Installer.**

Now Android studio work like charm in Windows.
Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I have found than my anti-spyware consider the jar files like archive. So I had exclude them from scan, but it's not very secure ....

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook that I use for Android Studio and when I started out it was completely unusable taking 5 to 10 minutes for a build even for the smallest app. The Android emulator still does not work. Two things made the system usable. More memory added - I originally had 2GB and now have 8GB ... and using actual Android hardware connected via USB.

My MacBook spec is as follows - macOS Sierra Version 10.12.3 MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2010) Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo Memory 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3 Graphics NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB Serial Number - oops!

The phone I use for build is an LG Sporty using Android 4.4.2 KitKat

Android Studio has the Intel HAXM extensions loaded and switched on.