# I can't edit studio.exe file in Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio 1.3 (I think it was the latest version) in a 4GB RAM pc, I've searched about how to make Android Studio take less memory so that I can run it better in my low spec pc, so far I've found the following questions:

- [Android Studio is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265819/android-studio-is-very-slow)
- [Android studio takes too much memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176353/android-studio-takes-too-much-memory)

In those question people suggested to low the memory value in the `Xmx` attribute  from `750m` to `256m` in the studio.exe vmoptions file the folder `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions` I looked in the offcial documentation here: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/configuration and there it says that is not recomended to edit those files, they advice to create a custom file, but I don't know how to do this.

Questions:

1) Should I create a whatever.exe vmoptions file in that folder with the change? and what should I do with the original file? and how android studio would know to read from my custom file instead of the original file.

2) In the official documentation says that edit that file but it says that that file is in this path `%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio.exe.vmoptions and/or %USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio64.exe.vmoptions` but I can't find the file in that path, instead I founded in this path `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions`.

What I did before asking:

Before asking i tried to edit this file `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions` but it says that this file is already opened by another program or that it can't be saved.

I did this with android studio closed and I pretty sure that this file it's not opened by another program.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late but i recently faced these issues. So here's what you can do
1. No need to create a new file. Just edit studio.exe.vmoptions.
2. Path is OK i.e. the bin folder.

As far as edit goes its a screw up from the editor. The real problem is that you may not have permission on the parent folder(bin). Just change the permissions for your user or all users for that matter if its not a problem. Run the -R command to do this recursively.then try and edit. should work just fine. Restart and you should see the improvement.